# dropdown hover issue(jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, hover, drop-down-menu

I have made a simple dropdown menu, this works fine but i want to add some space between the button and the dropdown menu(between bottom button/link and top dropdown menu).

The issue, if i dont add space between the button and dropdown menu it works fine, but once that i add space between them the dropdown menu goes back to hide once i leave the button.

I can make the li taller on hover but the li has style attached to it so i cant do much with this(also the a elements has fixed style attached to it).

So how can i keep the dropdown menu alive if its got space between it if i hover its parent li?

The jQuery code

```
    $('#sub-menu li').hover(function(){
        $(this).children('ul').stop(true,true).fadeIn(100);
    },function(){
        $(this).children('ul').stop(true,true).fadeOut(100);
    });
```

Basic html code

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link</a>
            <ul>
                <li>dropdown menu</li>
                <li>dropdown menu</li>
                <li>dropdown menu</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include your css and what it is you're doing to add space (margin, padding, absolute position, etc.)?

Comment: You can maybe add a border-bottom to main list li on hover. Make it thick and the same color as your header background, so it will act as a padding you need between the dropdown and the menu button. I haven't checked it though.

Comment: where is button and  to whom you assign `id="sub-menu"` ; `ul` or `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to do this is to set up a timer to close the submenu on the parent's mouseleave event, but cancel the timer if you mouseenter on the submenu. Setting this timer for 150-250ms usually gives plenty of time for a moderately slow-moving mouse to preserve the intended behavior, but doesn't feel too laggy when the menu *is* intended to close.

Not tested, more like pseudocode, just to show the general approach:

```
var submenuTimer = null;

$('#sub-menu li')
   .mouseenter(function(){
      $(this).children('ul').stop(true,true).fadeIn(100);
   })
   .mouseleave(function{
      submenuTimer = 
       setTimeout(
        function(){ $(this).children('ul').stop(true,true).fadeOut(100) }, 200
       );
   }); 

$('#sub-menu li ul').mouseenter(function(){ clearTimeout(submenuTimer });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand, although the css would be very helpful here.  I believe your child `ul` has `position:abosolute` and you have a `hover` on the parent `li`.  When the two are together, you can move your mouse from one to the other without leaving the `li` but once you put a gap between the two, moving your mouse from the link to the `ul` menu leaves the parent `li` causing the `mouseleave` to fire.

The way I would probably deal with this would be as follows.  Instead of re-positioning the child `ul`, wrap that `ul` in a div.  Put a `padding-top` on the div with as much space as you want.  Then move all of the positioning css and jquery stuff to show/hide/position the div instead. In this way, going from the link to the menu `ul` would not hit empty space and hide, it would instead move into the transparent div which is still part of the parent `li` and the menu would not hide.

Hope that helps, again css would be helpful to see exactly what you're doing.

EDIT:  Created a fiddle to demonstrate the idea.  The first link shows the problem, 2nd shows the fix, with a border to show what's actually happening and the 3rd is the actual fix.

http://jsfiddle.net/fTmLh/

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to just increase the bottom padding in your `<LI>` tags for the top level links. create a new class specifically for them or add it on-the-fly, like this:

```
   <li style="padding-bottom: 8px;">
```